# What's wrong with Aptana RadRails Eclipse update site?

Tags: ruby, eclipse, aptana

I'm trying to install Aptana Studio as Eclipse plugin in Eclipse 3.3 (Europa), and I'm following instructions on [this link](http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Plugging_Aptana_into_an_existing_Eclipse_configuration). However, the recommended update address for Eclipse 3.3 http://update.aptana.com/install/studio/3.2/ returns the following error message:

```
"Unable to access site: "http://update.aptana.com/install/studio/3.2/" [Server returned HTTP response code: "403 Forbidden" for URL: http://update.aptana.com/install/studio/3.2/.]"
```

The latest version does install on Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede), however I'm trying to add a bit of Ruby to existing Java-based projects and 3.3 environment my team currently uses.

Questions:

1. Is this only a temporary error, am I doing something wrong?
2. Did someone get Aptana Studio to work with Eclipse 3.3?
3. Is there a way to install only RadRails plugin without complete Aptana Studio? It seems to include a bunch of stuff I don't really need.

Idea here is to integrate a bit of Ruby into existing Java project, but so far Ruby has been pain in the buttocks to get working. Switching to NetBeans or installing Aptana as standalone are not really options I'd like to consider, and I'll switch to Eclipse 3.4 if I have to, but to be honest I'm currently at the point where I'm seriously considering ditching Ruby as "not mature enough" and considering other options (like Groovy for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [ticket 3913](http://support.aptana.com/asap/browse/STU-3913) mentioning this workaround:

manually modify the following line in the feature.xml file under C:\Program Files\Aptana\Aptana Studio 1.2\features\com.aptana.ide.feature.framework.air_1.2.5.*:

```
<update label="%updateSiteName" url="http://update.aptana.com/update/air/3.2/"/>
```

to

```
<update label="%updateSiteName" url="http://update.aptana.com/update/air/1.5/3.2/"/>
```

But in your case, both

```
http://update.aptana.com/install/studio/3.2
http://update.aptana.com/install/studio/1.5/3.2
```

redirect to:

```
 http://update15.aptana.org/studio/26124/3.2
 http://update15.aptana.org/studio/26124/1.5/3.2
```

So... may be a new ticket to [Aptana support](http://support.aptana.com/asap/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&mode=hide&pid=10002&sorter/order=DESC&sorter/field=priority&resolution=-1&component=10018) is in order.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using Ruby Developer Tools as described [here](http://www.napcs.com/howto/railsonwindows.html#_Toc111133461), which were enough for my needs at this point.